# Conditions for a search form

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I want to create a directory for accountants, and I want to create and advanced search form such as:

If the user enter: ***Lara*** and there is no accountants with this name I want to suggest accountants that his name contains 'L' 'A' 'R'?

So the problem is how to create this using SQL query because I don't know number of letters the user enter?

Comment: Its a programming choice, whenever the user hits search, then first do a full text match. If that query returns zero rows, then you try to do another query with first 3 letters of name like:

select * from tbl where name like '%' . substr($_POST['name'], 0, 3)

and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user is not found, use str_split to break the string into an array of 1 letter, then loop through the array and query them using LIKE '%$string%'.

```
// If user not found
if(!(mysqli_num_rows > 0)) {
    $array = str_split($search);
    // If search is two separated words, to remove space and reorder array, use this line instead:
    // $array = str_split(str_replace(" ", "", $array));

    for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        $char = $array[$i];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%$char%'";
        $result = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, $sql));
        echo $result['name'];
    }
```

Comment: this help me to have an idea, i will add 4 loops to search by 4,3,2 and 1 letter, Nice

Comment: You can do that too, however, you have to consider if the search by user is >10 chars long, your script might take a longer time to load. Happy to help.